# Extract URL Query Parameters from Request URL in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Is there any way I could fetch the GET URL Query String Parameters from any certain URL in my Angular Service?

For E.g. Suppose I have a URL = "http:localhost/?id=123&name=abc";
or URL = "http://www.myexamplewebsite.com?id=123&name=abc";

```
// in my service.ts
public myFunction(): Observale<any>
{
 let getVariable= this.http.get(URL);
 return getVariable.pipe(map(response => <Object>response), catchError(error => this.handleError(error)));
}
```

So either in my **component.ts** or **service.ts** is there any way I could extract this id & name? I am new with this topic.

Note: I am not running that URL in my route. So *this.route.snap.params* function didn't help.

Comment: have you used angular router in this code or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Angular's [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams). Import this: `import { HttpClient,HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';` and use `get(paramName)`or  `getAll()`as String[].

Here is another example of how you can get the Params: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pass-url-parameters-query-strings/

Answer (score -1):

You can get the params by injecting `Activatedroute` in the component constructor:

```
constructor(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    let id = activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['id'];
    let name = activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['name'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in your component do like this.

import it.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

then in constructor

```
private route: ActivatedRoute,
```

and then you can get param like this.

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
});
```

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-query-params)

try this [url](https://angular-routing-query-params.stackblitz.io/my-page?a=aaa&b=bbb) and check console. you will get query params.

let me know if you still have issue.

you can also check on this url - https://angular-routing-query-params.stackblitz.io/?abc=test&xyz=test2

output will be like this

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The **ActivatedRoute** class has a **queryParams** property that returns an **observable** of the query parameters that are available in the **current url**.

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  order: string;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.route.queryParams
        .filter(params => params.order)
        .subscribe(params => {
         console.log(params); // {order: "popular"}

         this.order = params.order;
         console.log(this.order); // popular
      });
   }
}
```

[Click here for complete article, its easy and best](https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/)